# Calling NProgress from Angular 2 function

Tags: angular

I'm using [NProgress](https://github.com/rstacruz/nprogress) in my Angular 2 app. I have used Gulp to concat and minify a bunch of JavaScript into a "combined.min.js" file that also includes NProgress.

I can successfully use NProgress like this:

```
declare var NProgress: any;

...

ngOnInit() : void {

    // Start progress bar
    NProgress.start();

}
```

But when I try to fire NProgress on events, like submitting a form:

```
onSearchFormSubmit() {

    // Start progress bar
    NProgress.start();

    validate form, perform HTTP calls via service etc...

}
```

It won't work. 
How come NProgress is out of reach for my custom events but can be reached by lifecycle hooks?

Comment: strange, i tried to fire it on some button click and it works OK... https://plnkr.co/edit/6rOZqTiX3vsEGElMVuCe?p=preview